# Multiple Implement statements vs. Interface Extend

Tags: php, oop

I have a web app with a "Semi-MVC" structure (It consists of Classes, Controllers, Views) and would like to know how to solve one problem.

My controllers are currently in this format:

```
class {ControllerName} extends Core implements PostController {
```

My `PostController` starts like this:

```
interface PostController extends Controller {
```

Now, would it be better to just structure the controllers in this way:

```
class {ControllerName} extends Core implements Controller, PostController {
```

There is only one disadvantage of the latter that I could think off is harder refactoring.

Could anyone shine some light on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning to remove "PostController"? If not, there's no added benefit to implementing an interface that PostController already extends

Comment: I may have not been a clear enough. What I was thinking of having is either PostController extends Controller and {Controller} Implements Post Controller OR PostController Standalone and {Controller} Implmenets, Controller, Post Controller.

Comment: Yeah - I think class PostController should extend a class Controller, and class Controller should implement Controller. class Controller could also implement interface PostController since it's Post specific - class Controller would also extend Core

Comment: Why would anything `extend` something that is called `Core`. This looks like a proper god object.

Comment: @PeeHaa You are completely right. The reason why I have a Core class is because it has methods which are useful across the whole app. Would it be better to try and take out some methods and let's say put them in a class called ControllerClass which would extend all controllers?